# Can't I serialize the Dictionary used by Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to see the Dictionary used by Unity on the Inspector. But I don't know if it's possible or not, and I don't know how.

Please tell me how to see the Dictionary on the inspector. Or you can tell me about other data structures similar to Dictionary in Unity.

Comment: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/serializabledictionary-90477

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is **no**, you can't serialize them.

But you have some options, I'll provide you with one.

Suppose you want to create a `Dictionary<string, int>`. You can create a class/struct that holds this information:

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class StringIntPair {
    public string key;
    public int value;
}
```

And then, in your code, you can create a `List<StringIntPair>`, that will be visible on your inspector. This way you can set the values you want in the inspector.

Lastly, you can create a `Dictionary<string, int>` and populate it in `Awake` / `Start` method as you wish:

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public List<StringIntPair> exposedDictionary; 
    Dictionary<string, int> hiddenDictionary;

    void Awake(){
        foreach(StringIntPair pair in exposedDictionary)
            hiddenDictionary[pair.key] = pair.value;
    }    
}
```

And then you can use `hiddenDictionary` in the code as you wish.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. You should have suggested implementing the ISerializationCallback interface and you’d have been essentially correct. You’re more correct though.